# HTML Help: How do I make the width of an image fit the entire container

Tags: html

I want that banner image to fit the white container instead of go over the side to the right, but I can't seem to ignore the margin on the left. I've tried all I know; from max-width to setting the margin at 0px but nothing works.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<p style="text-align: center;" dir="ltr">
  <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-504" title="bannercommunity" 
       src="image.png"
       alt="" width="960" height="140" />
</p>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can see that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help folks, but I discovered that by adding

'position: relative; left: -20px; width: 960px;'

in the styles field did the trick for me. So, setting the position of the image relative to the container, then matching the image width to the width of the container (while adding a minus number in order to nullify the left margin) worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `width: 100%` to the `<img>`.  Note that having the browser resize images is inefficient, so you should avoid it if you can and resize the image to the correct size that you want to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am against inline styles, I would suggest you to go with this:

**CSS Way**

```
.body .wp-image-504.aligncenter { width: 100% !important; }
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Remove the `width` and `height` values, give the style this way.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you need to add style="display: inline-block;" to the parent P tag of the image. Or you have to remove style="display: block;" in the "aligncenter" class of this image. Both of them will solve your problem.

---

Thanks Nick's suggestion, I've revised my answer in comment.

Comment: Inline-block has several quirks with different browsers and removing the block setting from the image has no effect on this image - it's also a class, probably reused so changing it will affect other parts of the site. You should try your solution with firebug etc. before you teach someone else awful habits.

Comment: Actually, you have to wrap your image in a DIV to achieve your proper result. Just like this will work: <div class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-504"><img width="960" height="140" style="width:100%"  title="bannercommunity" src="http://av5theapiaryconz.avatar.net.nz/wp-content/uploads/community/bannercommunity.png" alt=""></div>  The <IMG> is not the same as <DIV>.

Comment: Hi, Nick, thanks for your suggestion. I revised my answer in comment.

Comment: Why would you add more markup to change style? That's an even worse habit to teach.

Comment: <Img> has different property than <Div>. If you want to use "margin: 0 auto" properly (plus other styles and classes), you have to apply it to <DIV> tag but not <Img> tag.

Comment: Yes, I get your reasoning, but actually image will behave the same while it has a set width and is set to block. You still shouldn't add elements just for styling. In this example the left indent is caused by padding so there isn't actually a call for it to be centered. If you use Chrome browser you can inspect the source of live samples like this and actually change values to see the effect they have. It's really useful